# Getting the widgets selector in Widget Factory?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there any way to get the selector used to call my widget?

For example, if my selector is $("input [Title*='Cost Center']"), I want my widget to be able to see "input [Title*='Cost Center']".

I found this post [Accessing .selector within a JQuery UI Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986402/accessing-selector-within-a-jquery-ui-widget) which might suggest how it can be done but cannot begin to understand it.  If this is an answer how do I implement it?   My widget name is PNC_ERA.simpleDialogListSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out:

**HTML**

```
<div id='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
```

**Widget**

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("test.testwidget", {
        _create: function () {
            this.element.text('Selector: ' + this.options.selector)
        },
    });
}(jQuery));
```

and the code from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986402/accessing-selector-within-a-jquery-ui-widget) that you found already

```
// Save the original factory function in a variable
var testFactory = $.fn.testwidget;

// Replace the function with our own implementation
$.fn.testwidget = function(obj){
    // Add the selector property to the options
    $.extend(obj, { selector: this.selector });

    // Run the original factory function with proper context and arguments
    return testFactory.apply(this,arguments);
};
```

**Usage**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').testwidget({});
    $('.test').testwidget({});
});
```

Here is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/at35gd4d/1/)

Comment: Thanks!   This is exactly what I needed to finish my project.  I guess I will need to deep dive into widget factory to see what it is doing. :)